# Organic traffic for a particular domain

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have one property and one view where i track traffic for multiple domains. For ex: example.com, one.example.com, two.example.com, example2.com

Now, I want to get organic traffic for one.example.com in the same view. I use like this, ACQUISITION --> Channels --> Default channel grouping as primary dimension & Page as secondary dimension. In the filter, i filtered Channels with Organic search and in Page i filter with containing match example2.com. Is this good to go or should i choose Landing page as secondary dimension instead of Page.

And in what context we have to use Page & Landing Page dimension?

Regards,
Magesh

Answer (score 0):

If your pages in the path in the report are composed of a domain and a page path, it is a right way. Alternatively, you can filter by the 'host name'.

There is also a special report for landing pages, you can use that and as a secondary dimension the channel grouping (and filter for organic).